# Fetching Nested JSON Arrays with retrofit?

Tags: java, json, android-studio, retrofit2

### I searched a lot in Google to find a way to use Nested Json Arrays with Retrofit, but it is useless
Most of what I found talks about using JSON Objects with retrofit
And my main issue is how to use the nested Array list inside call method to get data from the server
I have this
JSON

```
   {
    "orders": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "OrderDate": "2020-07-01",
            "order_details": [
                {
                    "detail_ID": "1",
                    "description": "new order",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "item_ID": "1",
                            "item_name": "milk",
                            "Quantity": "4",
                            "Price": "56.0",
                            "UnitOfMeasure": "unit"
                        },
                        {
                            "item_ID": "1",
                            "item_name": "nuts",
                            "Quantity": "6",
                            "Price": "500",
                            "UnitOfMeasure": "unit"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }      
   
    ]
}
```

And those my other classes

### Item.java

```
public class Item {

@SerializedName("item_ID")
@Expose
private String itemID;
@SerializedName("item_name")
@Expose
private String itemName;
@SerializedName("Quantity")
@Expose
private String quantity;
@SerializedName("Price")
@Expose
private String price;
@SerializedName("UnitOfMeasure")
@Expose
private String unit_Of_Measure;

public String getItemID() {
return itemID;
}

public void setItemID(String itemID) {
this.itemID = itemID;
}

public String getItemName() {
return itemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
this.itemName = itemName;
}

public String getQuantity() {
return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getPrice() {
return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
this.price = price;
}

public String getUnitOfMeasure() {
return unitOfMeasure;
}

public void setUnitOfMeasure(String unitOfMeasure) {
this.unitOfMeasure = unitOfMeasure;
}

}
```

### Order.java

```
public class Order {

@SerializedName("orders")
@Expose
private List<Order_> orders = null;

public List<Order_> getOrders() {
return orders;
}

public void setOrders(List<Order_> orders) {
this.orders = orders;
}

}
```

### OrderDetail.java

```
public class OrderDetail {

@SerializedName("detail_ID")
@Expose
private String detailID;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("items")
@Expose
private List<Item> items = null;

public String getDetailID() {
return detailID;
}

public void setDetailID(String detailID) {
this.detailID = detailID;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
this.items = items;
}

}
```

### Order_.java

```
public class Order_ {

@SerializedName("ID")
@Expose
private String iD;
@SerializedName("OrderDate")
@Expose
private String orderDate;
@SerializedName("order_details")
@Expose
private List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = null;

public String getID() {
return iD;
}

public void setID(String iD) {
this.iD = iD;
}

public String getOrderDate() {
return orderDate;
}

public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
this.orderDate = orderDate;
}

public List<OrderDetail> getOrderDetails() {
return orderDetails;
}

public void setOrderDetails(List<OrderDetail> orderDetails) {
this.orderDetails = orderDetails;
}

}
```

### ApiInterface.java

```
@GET("orders")
Call<Order> getAllOrders();
```

Now I want to get order_detail, item data inside this function

```
  order.enqueue(new Callback<Order>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Order> call, Response<Order> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                 //here .................. 

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TaskResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

I will be so grateful who can help me

Comment: What's problem you has?

Comment: I want to get the data of  List<OrderDetail> getOrderDetails()  inside  this function

Comment: public void onResponse(Call<Order> call, Response<Order> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                 //here .................. 

                }
            }

Comment: when response is success,use response..body() get Order and process,this has any other problem？